# Elasticsearch dayOfWeek aggregation from timestamp [UTC] in different timezone

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Given **timestamp** in UTC format in elasticsearch documents.

The week day and hour of the day aggregations can be retrieved using inline scripts eg.

```js
    "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "doc['eventTime'].date.dayOfWeek"
        }
```

From above weekDay buckets will be evaluated on the basis of UTC time.

**Ques: How can we get the week day buckets in other timezone ?**
   eg. Asia/Singapore timezone from UTC timezone.

Comment: This question has been asked in a similar format before. See this link  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-it-possible-to-apply-a-timezone-to-a-date-in-a-scripted-field/65372

Comment: Thanks @PillHead, I used 
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "doc['eventTime'].date.dayOfWeek",
          "params": {
            "timeZone" : "GMT+9"
          }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Found later. It's the same 
[In Elasticsearch, how can I apply a timezone to a scripted date operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476135/in-elasticsearch-how-can-i-apply-a-timezone-to-a-scripted-date-operation/46830875#46830875)

```
   "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "inline": "doc['eventTime'].date.dayOfWeek",
      "params": {
        "timeZone" : "GMT+9"
      }
    }
```